# How to package Tcl libraries in my own program?

Tags: package, tcl, portability, init

In my c++ program, I used Tcl library and linked libtcl8.5.so, but the target hosts don't have tcl8.5, so I copied the libtcl8.5.so and  tcl8.5 dir which contains init.tcl there, and set the environmet variable TCLLIBPATH to path/to/copied/tcl8.5, but when my program call Tcl_Init, it failed and said “package not known”.

It seems the copied tcl8.5/ cannot be init correctly.
How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change the location of the script library directory (`tcl8.5/` in your case), you need to tell the shared library part of Tcl where it is. You do this using the `TCL_LIBRARY` environment variable, which if set should contain the *absolute* path that is the location of that directory (technically, the directory that contains `init.tcl`).
In a normal installation of Tcl, the correct location of that directory is baked directly into the shared library, but when you move things round (or when you are running Tcl's `make test`) the environment variable allows you to override.

You might wish to look into alternate packaging mechanisms; there have already been a few questions in the [tcl](/questions/tagged/tcl) tag on this matter (but the usual favorite — a starkit — is probably not suitable for your case given the fact that the program is mainly C++).

Comment: You could use a basekit dll or stardll (http://wiki.tcl.tk/15969). There you could link the C++ app to a dll that also includes a VFS containing any scripts required. By default such an entity contains the Tcl core scripts already.